# Pass HttpClient to class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac, .net-4.8

I have an order management system which sends emails via an external system. The external system is accessed via http calls. The order management has mainly 3 projects: a class library, web api2, and mvc app. In the class library thats where the service for interacting with email system resides. I have wired up all my dependencies using Autofac. I am thinking of creating the httpclient in the web api project so that it gets passed down to the class library. In ASP.NET core its possible but I am not sure of how to do it in .net 4.8.

For context the scenario is as follows:
User will place orders using the mvc app which calls the web api. The web api just provides endpoints for all the logic in the class library. When a user places an order they are supposed to receive an email with the order details. The class library calls an external system to send the email. The class library have an interface called IMessagingService which has one method SendEmailAsync. The implementation of this service MessagingService is the one requiring an httpclient

IMessagingService:

```
public interface IMessagingService
{
    Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string message);

}
```

Messaging Service:

```
public class MessagingService : IMessagingService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MessagingService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string message)
    {
       await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(/*content*/);
    }
}
```

Web API Global.asax.cs:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    internal static HttpClient _httpClient;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //Removed other lines

        Uri baseUri = new Uri("");

        _httpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = baseUri
        };

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(baseUri).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60 * 1000;
    }
}
```

Autofac configuration:

```
builder.RegisterType<MessagingService>()
            .WithParameter("httpClient", WebApiApplication._httpClient)
            .As<IMessagingService>()
            .InstancePerRequest();
```

Is it possible to pass the httpclient created in Global.asax.cs to the class library via Autofac? Any recommendations?

N.B. For now I can't migrate to ASP.NET core.

Comment: hmm, I thinks it is possible, I've had a similar problem before, I used NInject.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. The Autofac code provided seems to do what you want. What is the problem so far ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand The problem is I am getting null.

Comment: Did you try debug? Does _httpClient is null during registration?

Comment: @Hostel How do I check if its null during registration?

Comment: Debug application. Put breakpoint on registration and check if variable is null or not.

Comment: Just did. _httpClient on registration is null.

Comment: @Munhu it looks like registration is made before Application_Start execution. Application_Start creates new reference, but Autofac stores old (null). You should reorganize your code.

Comment: @Hostel you are I reorganized my code and its now working. Put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If during registration in Autofac `_httpClient` is null then for me it looks like registration is made before execution of `Application_Start`. `Application_Start` creates new reference, but Autofac stores old reference (null). You should reorganize your code.